# iOS In House app - Unable to download application

Tags: ios, iphone-developer-program, distribute, in-house-distribution

I'm trying to distribute an In House app, but when I try to install the app I get an error "Unable to download application".

```
Nov 12 12:33:41 iPhone-Rick installd[31] <Error>: 0x2ffc6000 handle_install: Install of "/var/mobile/Media/Downloads/1532059304834931943/8956635784114205146" requested by itunesstored

��Nov 12 12:33:43 iPhone-Rick installd[31] <Error>: 0x2ffc6000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Installing app com.Tim-Online.T-S-Zeeland

��Nov 12 12:33:43 iPhone-Rick installd[31] <Error>: Nov 12 12:33:43  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf CriticalExtensions IssuerCommonName]

��Nov 12 12:33:44 iPhone-Rick installd[31] <Error>: 0x2ffc6000 verify_signer_identity: MISValidateSignatureAndCopyInfo failed for /var/tmp/install_staging.qVkZ5j/foo_extracted/Payload/T&S Zeeland.app/T&S Zeeland: 0xe8008017

��Nov 12 12:33:44 iPhone-Rick installd[31] <Error>: 0x2ffc6000 do_preflight_verification: Could not verify executable at /var/tmp/install_staging.qVkZ5j/foo_extracted/Payload/T&S Zeeland.app
��
Nov 12 12:33:44 iPhone-Rick itunesstored[70] <Error>: 0x1b6e000 MobileInstallationInstall: failed with -1

��Nov 12 12:33:44 iPhone-Rick installd[31] <Error>: 0x2ffc6000 install_application: Could not preflight application install

��Nov 12 12:33:44 iPhone-Rick installd[31] <Error>: 0x2ffc6000 handle_install: API failed
```

Here's an overview of my Xcode settings: http://rido.me/hI26

And here's a screenshot of my Organiser -> Distribute screen: http://rido.me/9C5g

Does somebody know how I can fix this problem? I've tried everything but I can't find the solution..

Many thanks!

Comment: in ur xcode settings.. make sure even the debug code signing matches the distribution profile not only the release

Comment: That didn't help :( I've tried, but same error...

Comment: are you sure your distribution profile is for adhoc distribution??

Comment: Yes I'm sure, check my screenshot: http://rido.me/kCqN

Comment: Your screenshot says In-House, not Adhoc.

Comment: Yes that's right. It's an In-House app, not Adhoc.

Comment: how did you solve this?

Comment: @JoãoNunes There were some "dot" files in the project directory. Try the terminal command "dot_clean" to clean your project directory and rebuild your project.